# Turn iOS Device into AirPlay Speaker

Tags: ios, audio, airplay

I'm fiddling with an app, and I'm also aware that apps made by developers that allow an iOS Device to receive an audio stream from another iOS Device or iTunes.  So I'd like to implement it and possibly find a method within Apple's guidelines, allowing audio to be streamed.  I've tried looking for everything, but I can't find where to start.  Any ideas, a place to start, maybe even a point of direction would be great.

Comment: after looking at airfoil ( paid app ) i now have a similar question as yours. I will post here if I can crystal something meaningful in next few days. but if you have any leads pls post. tx.

Answer (score 0):

chekout the airspeaker project on github.

https://github.com/chenkaigithub/AirSpeaker

I was able to run it on iOS simulator 6.0 and then use my iphone to stream audio.
However if I try to stream from iTunes 11 it does not work ( iTunes lists the device in airplay list but , on selection , prompts with error "airplay device is not compatible with this version of iTunes." )